# Can I display a single PS4 console on 2 different game monitors for the purpose of multi-player gaming (split-screen over 2 monitors)?

Tags: ps4, call-of-duty-black-ops-3

I have 2 50 inch HD televisions I would like to place side by side for hardcore Black Ops III gaming (tournament gaming) The split screen option is ok but it is a bit cramped when using a pair of large assault rifle controllers.

So, we would like to get player 1 on monitor 1 and player 2 on monitor 2.

Is it possible? If so, can anyone elaborate 'how to' info for setup?

Comment: I don't have the time to do the research required for an answer, but Sony talked about using 3D technology a while back, where a split screen would instead render each players screen to a different side of the 3D lenses. I know they did release it, though I can't recall if it ended up being an inherent feature of the console, or whether you would have to use one of their own 3D TVs. I suspect the later, as you would also need specific glasses.

Comment: [Using DualPlay or SimuView on any split screen game, using any console](http://www.tweaking4all.com/video/gaming/split-screen-game-full-screen/)

Comment: @Timelord64, answer edited to show why that's just as bad an idea as any other - the image is still going to be stretched.  If the game + console actually supported SimulView, it would take the aspect ratio stretching into account when sending the images.  Since it doesn't, things are going to look very, very wonky.  It also assumes that the TV has passive 3D support, which never really caught on and is rather unlikely.

Comment: @Timelord64 thanks for the link. i havent had a chance to look at it yet but sounds interesting. im not using any 3D TV. instead, i have two Vizio 50in 1080p TVs that I am using at game monitors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you really want is for the game to not be split screen anymore - you want one player on screen 1, full screen, and one player on screen 2, also full screen.

Unfortunately, this isn't going to be possible.  There's no support in the PS4 for this, and there's no support in the game for this either.  The PS3 had something called "SimulView" but this isn't supported in PS4 games to date.

There are various solutions external to the PS4, but the problem is that the aspect ratio of each player's portion of the screen won't match up with the full size of each display.  For instance, [a link in the comments](http://www.tweaking4all.com/video/gaming/split-screen-game-full-screen/) talks about using a passive 3D display (assuming your TV or TVs support passive 3D) to get a full screen image out of a split screen game.

The problem here is that the game is still only sending half a screen's worth of pixels to each player, and then that image is stretched to fill the entire screen.  It's going to look very out of proportion - HUD elements will look double height at the same width, etc.

Thus, there aren't any better options than just running the console to a HDMI splitter and displaying the same split-screen image on both TVs.

The only way to get exactly what you want is to pick up a second PS4 for your second TV.

Comment: yeah, i didnt truly mean split screen but i was trying to think of a way to get the point across. yeah, i think the only way is a second console and second game as well. thanks for the explanation though. i still found it informative.